# botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AuthFailure)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, botocore

Not sure what's going on here... I am having this error when doing a simple describe-instance using the boto3 client.

Error:
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AuthFailure) when calling the DescribeInstances operation: AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials

Code snippet:

```
  def get_ec2_client(aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key, region_name):

    return boto3.client(
            'ec2',
            aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id,
            aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key,
            region_name=region_name
        )

  instances=client.describe_instances()
```

I ran this in debug so I am sure that the creds are correct. I also use the same creds with the cli and it worked, so it is a bit confused what's going on.
This was working up till yesterday so I checked the boto3 and botocore modules updates. They are updated almost daily but I don't see any breaking changes in the latest updates.

I've been at this for some time and still couldn't find the issue. Any idea anyone?

Since I am facing this issue today I am using:
boto3                    1.15.11
botocore                 1.18.11

Comment: In the snipet, where do you call `get_ec2_client`? It is not shown.

Comment: Yes, your code seems to be `return`ing the `client`, and it never gets to the `describe_instances()` call. Also, rather than passing credentials, it is recommended that you use the AWS CLI `aws configure` command to store the credentials in a file. This way, boto3 will automatically find the credentials and you do not need to pass them when creating the `client`.

Comment: Thanks for your responses, a more complete picture of the code interaction..
The client is actually inside a method:
def get_ec2_snapshot(client):
   snap = client.describe_instances()
and this def itself called here:
def get_snapshot(creds):
     snap = get_ec2_snapshot(
                get_ec2_client(
                    creds.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
                    creds.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
                    region_name
                )
            )